# How correctly work with stub files of Laravel project in PhpStorm 2023?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, stub

After I installed stubs in Laravel 10 app  with command

```
php artisan stub:publish
```

and try to open one of *stub files, it is opened by kate of my Kubuntu 22.04.

In PhpStorm 2023.2 I applied command “Override file type” and selected "PHP", but it does not seems to be a good option as this file shows a lot of errors. I did not find any “stub” extension in command “Override file type” or some stubs in available plugins.

How can I use these files?

Comment: PhpStorm does not have any highlighting for Laravel .stub files. However, these files should be opened as plain text in IDE, not passed further to OS. Is there any chance you have ".stub" added as a file name pattern in "File | Settings | Editor | File Types > Files opened is associated applications"? Also, you may try adding ".stub" to the "File | Settings | Editor | File Types > Text".